# Cmake generate independent makefiles

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, platform-independent

We are moving from [MPC](http://www.ociweb.com/products/mpc&title=MPC&desc=+-+Object+Computing+Inc+-+A+Makefile+and+Project+file+Creator+program+that+generates+Make-specific+makefiles+or+visual+studio+project+files+from+platform-independent+build+files+and+template+files) to CMake.
We provide a lib with some samples. The samples are coming with makefiles.

The problem is that the makefiles, generated by cmake contains absolute paths but not relative ones:

```
# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    cd /.../Projects/cpp_trunk && $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /.../Projects/cpp_trunk/CMakeFiles /.../Projects/cpp_trunk/samples/CMakeFiles/progress.make
    cd /.../Projects/cpp_trunk && $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 samples/all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /.../cpp_trunk/CMakeFiles 0
```

So, when it is copied it's become broken.
It there any way to work it around?

UPD: I have read the [FAQ](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Why_does_CMake_use_full_paths.2C_or_can_I_copy_my_build_tree.3F), but my question is still taking place, perhaps somebody managed to get around?

Comment: Do you plan to ship the Makefiles along your library to a third party? In that case, the Makefiles generated by CMake aren't well suited. Maybe you can write a simple Makefile generator specifically suited for your examples, this can be done using CMake commands or a stand-alone tool.

Comment: @Lindydancer, Yes, and that is the problem. We didn't have to do anything manually when we used MPC. The question is how to generate Makefiles suitable for providing to the third party without using any stand-alone tool.

Comment: If you want them all to be on a standard form, then I would suggest that you take a look at the CMake command for writing to files, e.g. `file()` and and write one out yourself, alternatively you could use `configure()` and let CMake fill in the blanks. If you write your own tool, it can be started by CMake using `add_custom_command()`. Not pretty solutions, but it would work in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've done to get around this sort of thing is write a small wrapper Makefile around cmake.  I put the Makefile at the project root, with contents like this:

```
all: cmake

cmake:
    [ -f build/CMakeCache.txt ] && [ "$$(pwd)" != "$$(grep 'CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY:INTERNAL' build/CMakeCache.txt | cut -d '=' -f 2)" ] \
&& rm -rf build || true
    mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake ..
    make -C build

clean:
    rm -rf build
```

There's probably a cleaner way to do it, but it works for me:

```
make # build in one directory
cd ..
olddir=$(basename $OLDPWD) && rsync -ravz $olddir ${olddir}-test && cd ${olddir}-test # copy to another directory
make # running make in the new dir triggers a full rebuild
make # running make a second time in the new dir does not rebuild
```

Answer (score 2):

The makefiles created by CMake are not part of your source code base. The CMakeLists.txt files that you use as input to CMake *are* part of your source code base. When you copy your source code to a different place and want to build it there, build from your source code. That means re-running CMake. (And that's your workaround.)

I've been using CMake for over ten years continuously on one project. One of the handy tricks my team has learned is that you can have multiple copies of one part of your source code base on one development host that all share the same copy of the rest of your source code base. Try doing that with relative paths! We *rely* on the fact that every time we build source code in a new build directory, CMake will figure out the correct paths to all the source files, which are not necessarily the same relative to the new build directory as they were in the previous build.

Answer (score 0):

The build files that are generated by cmake (makefiles, ninja files, etc), are going to have hardcoded paths and other not-portable stuff in them. That's ok. Treat them as temporary files that are part of the build process. You will only version the CMakeLists.txt files, and then generate new makefiles (or whatever) on other machines or in other directories when you check it out. You can even have different people on the team using different build files - one person using makefiles, one person using eclipse+ninja, etc, all generated by cmake.